# Subsequence parttern matching for time series

Tags: machine-learning, classification, time-series, regression, pattern-recognition

I have a set of time series data (just like voice sequence data) with the pattern as shown in the first figure (theoretical data). The measured data is given as presented in the second figure. What I want to do is localizing/finding the subsequent pattern as shown in the red squares. Is there any algorithm to solve this problem? It looks like the classification/regression problem in machine learning, but I have no idea how to start it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you look into independent component analysis?

Comment: Not yet, is there any recommendation of literature? Thanks

Comment: ESL, Ch. 14.7 https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf

Comment: But on a second thought it might be a good problem for LSTM neural net: https://jjallaire.github.io/deep-learning-with-r-notebooks/notebooks/6.3-advanced-usage-of-recurrent-neural-networks.nb.html

Comment: Thanks, Peter! I will check them both. I have some basic idea about LSTM for prediction problem. Towards this problem, how do you consider them? Classification or regression?

Comment: is this purely ex post or with a predictive element in it. If ex post what stops you looking at the derivative/slope of the curve

Comment: Postprocessing. I have looked into slope, but the measureed data is not as perfect as the theoratical figure above. There are some small fluctuations. So pure derivative doesn't always work well.

Comment: what about something like $x_t - x_{t-1}$ or so as feature in some simple classification model?

Comment: Adjacent difference is too ideal duo to fluctuations, and $x_{t+n}-x_t$ is also not satisfied, as the setting of $n$ is an adding problem without specific/general criterion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *real* state of the art here is the Matrix Profile suite, developed by Eamonn Keogh and his team in University of California at Riverside (UCR). Here are some links to get you started:

- [Matrix Profile Foundation](https://matrixprofile.org/) homepage
- [The UCR Matrix Profile Page](https://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Eeamonn/MatrixProfile.html)
- [MPA: a novel cross-language API for time series analysis](https://joss.theoj.org/papers/10.21105/joss.02179) paper (2020) with links to Python, R, and Go implementations
- [Introducing matrixprofile-ts, a Python Library for Detecting Patterns and Anomalies in Massive Datasets](https://tech.target.com/2018/12/11/matrix-profile.html)
- [Towards a Near Universal Time Series Data Mining Tool: Introducing the Matrix Profile](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.03064) (PhD thesis)
- [100 Time Series Data Mining Questions (with answers!)](https://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Eeamonn/100_Time_Series_Data_Mining_Questions__with_Answers.pdf) (highly recommended high-level view)

You'll find links to implementations in the above stuff.

Apart from the team at UCR, there is another (and possibly more efficient) implementation of the relevant algorithms in the STUMPY Python package:

- STUMPY [documentation](https://stumpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) & [Github repo](https://github.com/TDAmeritrade/stumpy)
- [STUMPY: A Powerful and Scalable Python Library for Time Series Data Mining](https://joss.theoj.org/papers/10.21105/joss.01504) paper (2019)